# Admob Mediation with Adcolony and others

Tags: android, ios, admob, cocos2d-x-2.x, adcolony

I have been working on some android and iOS applications with cocos2dx 2.2.6 and have recently added AdMob integration. I understand this is a general question but I was wondering if anyone had any tips with how to make the most money with Admob. Specifically I have been having trouble with setting up Admob Mediation. I have tried to add Adcolony ads in addition to regular admob ads to my game but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get it out of the "pending" phase. Also if it did get out of this phase will I have to do anything special codewise to make it work? or will it just fill the container wtih Adcolony ads sometimes. If anyone has any knowledge of how this process works or how to optimally set up admob mediation that would be of great help to me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I generally get Adcolony out of the pending state by Integrating it as a standalone SDK. Once i see a test ad with Ad Colony, I then use Admob for mediation and add the Ad colony details to it. Also the documentation provided via Admob for mediation is fairly simple and straightforward and requires no additional coding to get it to work.